# PyQt Quickly Update QTextEdit like QAbstractItemModel

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside, pyside2

Is there any way to make a model to update a QTextEdit like the QAbstractItemModel.

The QAbstractItemModel/QAbstractTableModel has a `data (index[, role=Qt.DisplayRole])` method which is called whenever the view needs to display something. This allows me to make my own data structure to save data in python quickly. Is there any way to make a QTextEdit, QTextDocument, or QTextDocumentLayout work this way?

Right now I save data to a queue and periodically display the data by running `update_display` on a timer.

```
class QuickTextEdit(QtWidgets.QTextEdit):

    def update_display(self):
        for _ in range(len(self.queue)):
            text, fmt = self.queue.popleft()
            cursor = QtGui.QTextCursor(self.textCursor())
            cursor.beginEditBlock()

            # Move and check the position
            pos = cursor.position()
            cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
            is_end = cursor.position() == pos

            # Insert the text
            cursor.setCharFormat(fmt)
            cursor.insertText(text)
            cursor.endEditBlock()

            # Move the cursor
            if is_end:
                # Actually move the text cursor
                cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
                self.setTextCursor(cursor)
```

I found that this is much slower than the way a QAbstractTableModel/QTableView works.

I would like the widget to request data (instead of inserting) like the QAbstractItemModel. I tried using an html string in a QLabel.paintEvent, but couldn't get that to work properly. I really would just like an HTML Text Viewer for some data structure/model.

```
class QuickTextEdit(QtWidgets.QTextEdit):
    def data(self):
        return ''.join(('<font color="{color}">{text}</font>'.format(color=color, text=text)
                        for color, text in self.queue))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a simple model view setup yourself.

Here is some pseudo code:

```py
class TextEditView(QtWidgets.QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, model):
        connect(model.dataChanged, self.update_display)

    @SLOT
    def update_display(self):
         text = model.data()
         self.setText(text)

class TextEditModel(QObject):
    SIGNAL dataChanged
    def data(self):
        new_text = queue.get_nowait()
        return new_text

class WorkerThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def run(self):
        queue.put(new_data)
        model.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
```

Then in your thread you would first put the new data into the queue. And then issue a model.dataChanged signal. Then the view would poll the new data.

Alternatively you can skip the whole Model view separation and create a signal for `TextEditView` with the datatype you want.

Let me know how it goes.